# Interaction between ID token verification in server client libraries and Security Rules

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I recently asked [How to integrate security rules into Firestore client from Python's server client library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458980/how-to-integrate-security-rules-into-firestore-client-from-pythons-server-clien) where the answer clarified to me that security rules were not followed server-side. I've mostly pieced together what I need to do, but want confirmation:

I've read [Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) which explains how to verify that a user successfully signed in on the client like so:

```
decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
uid = decoded_token['uid']
```

At the same time, server client libraries bypass security rules. This means I cannot have this `uid` automatically incorporated into my Firestore client such that read/writes fail in accordance with my security rules.

Instead, given a document called `Collection/abc` like so:

```
{
    "user_id": "def" 
}
```

Because there is no way to rely on security rules (where'd I'd be able to enforce a match between `uid` and `user_id`) to automatically enforce whether this `uid` can actually access a document, I have to do something like this instead server-side:

```
my_document = firestore_client.collection("Collection").document("abc")

if my_document["user_id"] != uid:
    raise ValueError("User not properly authenticated")
```

i.e integrate what the security rules are trying to do into the code itself.

Is this the right understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your security rules are not enforced for code that accesses the database with administrative permission, your code will have to take its place.

The code you provided seems (at first glance) the equivalent of allowing the user access to a document that has a field `user_id` that has the value of the Firebase Authentication UID that is present in the ID token.